# How to change a dictionary in to a string

Tags: string, dictionary, type-conversion, converters

```
def dict_to_str(d):
    '''(dict) -> str
```

Returns a string containing each key and value in d. Keys and values 
are separated by a space. Each key-value pair is separated by a
comma.

```
>>> dict_to_str({3:4, 5:6})
'3 4, 5 6'
'''
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Specify the question. Write your attemps (homework)

Comment: i am trying to take the key value pairs in a dictionary and change them in to a string. So for a dict d = {1:2, 3:4} i would get a string of '1 2, 3 4' . The main restrictions that i have is that i cannot make it work for keys with more than one values attached to it. There needs to be a space between every value

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried. From there we can guide you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is in Python.

```
exDict = {1:3, 2:4}
# This will give you a string that looks like "{1: 3, 2: 4}".
stringDict = str(exDict)
```

At this point you have a string of the dict. What you need to do now is replace the curly brackets and colon with an empty space. This should give you the form you want.

```
for char in stringDict:
    if char in "{}:":
        stringDict = stringDict.replace(char, "")
```

That should do the trick.